# What Activity's lifecycle callbacks are executed when Android orientation is changed?

Tags: android

I got stuck while debugging a situation which involved orientation change and some null returns.

My question is divided into :

1) What  callbacks of Activity's lifecycle are executed when orientation is changed.

2) What  callbacks of Fragment's lifecycle are executed when orientation is changed.

3) If we merge point 2 and 3 (which is usually the case with fragments overlying an Activity), what will be the callback execution flow in terms of an Activity having a Fragment(flow of execution?).

**EDIT**

Shedding some light on the question, if no configChanges are defined in android manifest file i.e. :

> If any configuration change occurs that is not selected to be reported by that attribute, then instead of reporting it the system will stop and restart the activity (to have it launched with the new configuration).

What **Lifecycle callbacks** of activity and fragment will be executed?

Comment: http://7xi7e6.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/activity-fragment_lifecycle_4.png check this

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, in **AndroidManifest** add it to your activity: `android:configChanges="orientation"`
 
1). [onConfigurationChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration))
2). Nothing, but you can **implement your method** and call it from activity's onConfigurationChanged
3). The flow will be `Activity.onConfigurationChanged -> Fragment.yourMethod`

Hope this helps.

**UPDATED**

Here is your flow when your start activity first time:

> Activity.onCreate
>  Activity.onStart
>  Fragment.onAttach
>   Fragment.onCreate
>  Fragment.onCreateView
>   Fragment.onViewStateRestored
>  Fragment.onStart
>   Activity.onResume
>  Fragment.onResume

Here is flow after orientation changed:

> Activity.onPause
>  Fragment.onPause
>   Activity.onSaveInstanceState
>  Fragment.onSaveInstanceState
>   Activity.onStop
>  Fragment.onStop
>  Activity.onDestroy
>   Fragment.onDestroy
>  Fragment.onDetach
>  Fragment.onAttach
>   Fragment.onCreate
>  Activity.onCreate
>  Activity.onStart
>   Fragment.onCreateView
>  Fragment.onViewStateRestored
>   Fragment.onStart
>  Activity.onRestoreInstanceState
>   Activity.onResume
>  Fragment.onResume

Here is code to check it:

```
public class FooActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = FooActivity.class.getSimpleName() + "_TAG";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Activity.onCreate");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_foo);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new BarFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Activity.onPause");
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Activity.onStop");
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Activity.onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Activity.onResume");
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Activity.onStart");
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Activity.onConfigurationChanged");
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Activity.onSaveInstanceState");
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Activity.onRestoreInstanceState");
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class BarFragment extends Fragment {

        public BarFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Fragment.onCreateView");
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bar, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Fragment.onCreate");
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Fragment.onAttach");
            super.onAttach(activity);
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewStateRestored(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Fragment.onViewStateRestored");
            super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Fragment.onSaveInstanceState");
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Fragment.onResume");
            super.onResume();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Fragment.onStart");
            super.onStart();
        }

        @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Fragment.onConfigurationChanged");
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Fragment.onPause");
            super.onPause();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Fragment.onStop");
            super.onStop();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDetach() {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Fragment.onDetach");
            super.onDetach();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Fragment.onDestroy");
            super.onDestroy();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander. From  link :" instead of reporting it the system will stop and restart the activity (to have it launched with the new configuration)." This is the flow I am interested in, do you know which callbacks will be executed?

Comment: @Kay, you are welcome.`Activity.onSaveInstanceState` before destroing activity and `Activity.onRestoreInstaceState` after creating new activity. This callbacks should be invoked

Comment: Or You intersted in whole lifecycle? I don't understand your question

Comment: Ok, so onResume(), onPause() and other such lifecycle callbacks are not executed? I understand they wont if we provide configChanges in manifest, but what if no configChanges is defined?

Comment: Yes my question is regarding the lifecycle callbacks

Comment: I was gonna start the same, but thanks a ton. Beautiful!

Comment: Fragment `OnRestoreInstanceState` is not called ?

Answer (score 1):

**onConfigurationChanged()** method

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
// Checks the orientation of the screen
if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
    Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }  }
```

add this code in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
```

You can also check these [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration)) and [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration))

Comment: For any types of configuration changes you say that you handle there, you will receive a call to your current activity's `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration)` method instead of being restarted. If a configuration change involves any that you do not handle, however, the activity will still be restarted and `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration)` will not be called.

Comment: Restarted can mean onStart is called or onRestart is called.. which one is it? before restarting, current instance calls onpause or till on stop()?

Comment: here's something more [Handling Configuration Changes](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Configuration-Changes)  A Tutorial

Comment: That helps. I will either use config tag and override function OR not do it. Using just the tag and not overriding function is a hack that I won't wanna use/ bad programming skill. In my above or statement first part is very clear.

Comment: Android Documentation says the second part is difficult to implement, I want to implement that. Hence, still am confused what will be the lifecycle flow. Now gonna track the callbacks with logs and update the thread